# Error while installing scipy on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I am working on a windows machine and 2.7 version of python. I have already installed numpy and now I am trying to install scipy. I have tried installing it using the easy install command and by downloading a zip file and then running the setup.py file.

When I try installing it by the easy_install

```
c:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install scipy
Searching for scipy
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
Best match: scipy 0.13.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.3.zip#md5
=20ff3a867cc5925ef1d654aed2ff7e88
Processing scipy-0.13.3.zip
Writing c:\users\yash\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-k37as1\scipy-0.13.3\setup.
cfg
Running scipy-0.13.3\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\yash\appdata\loca
l\temp\easy_install-k37as1\scipy-0.13.3\egg-dist-tmp-yi3r5o
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:576: UserWarning: S
pecified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/ia32 is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:576: UserWarning: S
pecified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/compiler/lib/ia32 is inva
lid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:576: UserWarning: S
pecified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1522: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1531: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1534: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
error:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.

c:\Python27\Scripts>
```

And this is what happens when I run the setup.py file

```
C:\Users\Yash\Downloads\scipy-0.13.2\scipy-0.13.2>python setup.py install
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:576: UserWarning: S
pecified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/ia32 is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:576: UserWarning: S
pecified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/compiler/lib/ia32 is inva
lid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:576: UserWarning: S
pecified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
  libraries mkl_lapack95,mkl_blas95,mkl_intel_c,mkl_intel_thread,mkl_core,libiom
p5md,libifportmd not found in []
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\l
ibs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', '
C:\\Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\
Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1522: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs'
]
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1531: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1534: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 230, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 227, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in set
up
    config = configuration()
  File "setup.py", line 170, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 966, i
n add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, i
n get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 872, i
n _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\setup.py", line 12, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('integrate')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 966, i
n add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, i
n get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 872, i
n _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\integrate\setup.py", line 12, in configuration
    blas_opt = get_info('blas_opt',notfound_action=2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py", line 350,
 in get_info
    return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py", line 509,
 in get_info
    raise self.notfounderror(self.notfounderror.__doc__)
numpy.distutils.system_info.BlasNotFoundError:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.

C:\Users\Yash\Downloads\scipy-0.13.2\scipy-0.13.2>
```

I am new to python and I am not understanding why I am getting these errors. I don't see a folder in the Lib folder of Python27 and as expected I am getting an ImportError: No module named scipy error when I say import scipy on the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

You don't appear to have a compiler installed to compile scipy and its dependencies. This is a common issue on windows. You'll need to install a compiler (the long route) or download the pre-compiled binaries for windows (usually much more user-friendly for packages you need to use on windows).

> [Individual binary and source packages (from scipy.org/install.html)](http://www.scipy.org/install.html)
>
> The maintainers of many of the packages in the SciPy stack provide “official” binary installers for common Windows and OS-X systems that can be used to install the packages one by one. These installers are generally built to be compatible with the Python binaries available from python.org.

I'd try grabbing the latest version from sourceforge at http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/

Comment: The superpack at sourceforge was useful. Got scipy installed on my x64 Windows 7 for Python 3.4.

Comment: I've solverd a similar problem (wrong compiler version) by downloading it from Microsoft: http://aka.ms/vcpython27. More help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140192/microsoft-visual-c-compiler-for-python-2-7)

Answer (score 1):

Long I tried to establish a `SciPy` after setting `numpy`.
I too used https://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/
But I `win64`, but only under the `win32` website. Download and install `scipy-0.16.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe` and now `scipy` appears in the installed modules.