# Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7

Tags: python, visual-c++

I downloaded [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) , and install it, the full path of `vcvarsall.bat` is:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\vcvarsall.bat
```

But the following code can't return the path of it:

```
from distutils import msvc9compiler
msvc9compiler.find_vcvarsall(9.0)
```

The installer doesn't write the install information to the registry, and from the source code of `find_vcvarsall()`, it seems that it can't find the `vcvarsall.bat` file from `VS90COMNTOOLS` setting, because it requires that the name of the folder that contains `vcvarsall.bat` is `VC`:

```
productdir = os.path.join(toolsdir, os.pardir, os.pardir, "VC")
```

How can I use the compiler without modify registry or folder name?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Update setuptools to 6.0 or greater. In those version setuptools can autodetect Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 with the **vcvarsall.bat**.

Please reference to:

1. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/6.1#id4
2. https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issue/258

Comment: This was it for me. I was using virtual env, and it installed a old version of setup tools by default.

Comment: Well even though you have the last version of setuptools installed, as long as your setup.py uses disutils.core.setup, it won't detect the compiler. At least this was the case for me.

Answer (score 22):

Look in the `setup.py` file of the package you are trying to install. If it is an older package it may be importing `distutils.core.setup()` rather than `setuptools.setup()`.

I ran in to this (in 2015) with a combination of these factors:

1. The Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
2. An older package that uses `distutils.core.setup()`
3. Trying to do `python setup.py build` rather than using `pip`.

If you use a recent version of pip, it will force (monkeypatch) the package to use setuptools, even if its `setup.py` calls for distutils. However, if you are not using pip, and instead are just doing `python setup.py build`, the build process will use `distutils.core.setup()`, which does not know about the compiler install location.

---

### Solution

**Step 1:** Open the appropriate Visual C++ 2008 Command Prompt

Open the Start menu or Start screen, and search for "Visual C++ 2008 32-bit Command Prompt" (if your python is 32-bit) or "Visual C++ 2008 64-bit Command Prompt" (if your python is 64-bit). Run it. The command prompt should say Visual C++ 2008 ... in the title bar.

**Step 2:** Set environment variables

Set these environment variables in the command prompt you just opened.

```
SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
SET MSSdk=1
```

Reference http://bugs.python.org/issue23246

**Step 3:** Build and install

`cd` to the package you want to build, and run `python setup.py build`, then `python setup.py install`. If you want to install in to a virtualenv, activate it before you build.

Comment: I have a python package that uses numpy distutils for compiling fortran extensions, so I can't use setuptools hence it can't find visual studio.  This solves the problem perfectly.

Comment: changing the import to setuptools worked like a magic, gracias! I had tones of different c compilers installed but this thing was not able to detect them apparently. Now it can...

Answer (score 10):

Christian Long provides a practicable solution. But if you do not want to modify it in "Visual C++ 2008 32-bit/64-bit Command" every time, you can simply find out the location of "vcvarsall.bat", i.e. "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\vcvarsall.bat", and then modify find_vcvarsall(version) function in Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py

like this:

```
def find_vcvarsall(version):
    productdir= "C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Programs/Common/Microsoft/Visual C++ for Python/9.0"
    vcvarsall = os.path.join(productdir, "vcvarsall.bat")
    if os.path.isfile(vcvarsall):
        return vcvarsall
    else:
        return None
```

Simple, ugly but useful.

Note that Microsoft no longer lets you download the required Visual Studio 2008 VC++ Build Tools, but the file can be found in the archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20210106040224/https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/9/6/796EF2E4-801B-4FC4-AB28-B59FBF6D907B/VCForPython27.msi

Comment: Very helpful.  I tried countless other things and this did it for me.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue with this package, it seems that they didn't really test it with a clean installation.

In the end I just added a Key to create `COMPUTER\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VC` then I added a String Value with the name `productdir` with the value set to my path to vcvarsall.bat, which was the same as yours.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade your setuptools in the command line:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

The latest versions of setuptools above 6.0 should autodetect the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7