# Microsoft Compilers for Python 2.7..can't download it, what higher version should I use?

Tags: python, c++, windows, compiler-errors

I am trying to install a python package that needs a Windos C++ compiler
The install procedure sent me to this link:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

I am using Python 2.7 x86 on Win 7 x64
The version indicated on that page is not available anymore (Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 standalone: Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 (x86, x64) )

What can I do? Where can I find the above compiler ?

Comment: Did you look at [this one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) (also linked from that wiki page)?

Comment: How about you, did you look at that link :-) ? It is dead

Comment: Wow, that is weird, the link just worked for me, but now it doesn't anymore.

Comment: Very strange.  If I visit the link repeatedly, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  Perhaps something is wacky on Microsoft's server.  Anyway, you might try refreshing again and again and hope you get lucky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what is happening with Microsoft today or these days but here is the direct link
http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/9/6/796EF2E4-801B-4FC4-AB28-B59FBF6D907B/VCForPython27.msi

Alternatively you can search github, for "VCForPython27.msi site:github.com"

That will give you either the above link or links to files hosted on Github.

Comment: The link is now dead.

Answer (score 12):

The "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7" download has now been completely removed by Microsoft. (Which BTW, means the Chocolatey install won't work either as it was relying on the Microsoft website as a source.)

As a last resort, the file is available from the Internet Archive. Prefer any other source though, the last thing we want is to hammer the Wayback Machine with unnecessary download requests.

https://web.archive.org/web/20210106040224/https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/9/6/796EF2E4-801B-4FC4-AB28-B59FBF6D907B/VCForPython27.msi

Here are the hashes to verify integrity in case you grab the file from elsewhere:

```
   SHA-1: 7800d037ba962f288f9b952001106d35ef57befe
 SHA-256: 070474db76a2e625513a5835df4595df9324d820f9cc97eab2a596dcbc2f5cbf
 SHA-512: 155b52a2ed59730983346899a96f42eb76ff5b4c2b7deb8b5946008b95bb0c6c1e6da31c80b7c68f5fe6881ddaa65ce321c6a52f3b0fc34ee98b4dd8dfa42772
```

Comment: Needs to be mirrored somewhere for safety-- wayback just lost a ton of archives

Answer (score 0):

The [express versions of visual studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-express-vs) are free, I assume the command line compiler would work.

You might also need to read [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140192/microsoft-visual-c-compiler-for-python-2-7?rq=1)

Comment: Compiling extensions for 2.7 works best with the [VC++ Compiler for 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266). No currently supported version of Visual Studio Express will produce binaries that link with msvcr90.dll, which is required for 100% compatibility with the official 2.7 builds, in terms of interoperability of file streams, memory allocations, and per-thread locales.

Comment: From that package what exactly do I select under Programming languages and under Windows Web Development> The entire distribution  has 6G. This is what I was trying to avoid

Comment: @eryksun That is the problem, the link is dead

Comment: @user2059078, the link is not dead for me, but try Steve Dower's [AKA link](http://aka.ms/vcpython27). For me it resolves to the same path. Steve Dower is the Microsoft programmer on the Visual Studio team, and Python core developer, who requested Microsoft to distribute this unsupported version of VC++ for Python 2.7.

Comment: @user2059078, both links worked a minute ago when I posted the comments. But now I can't even reliably load the [Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/default.aspx). Clearly there are problems with the server at the moment. Try again later.

Comment: I don't have enough fingers for Microsoft's incompetency! https://github.com/reider-roque/sulley-win-installer/blob/master/VCForPython27.msi  If anybody is looking for this Google for VCForPython27.msi